# docker-compose tmpfs not working

Tags: docker-compose, tmpfs

I have a docker-compose file that I'm trying to secure by making the root volumes of the containers it creates read-only.

Relevant parts of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    read_only: true
    tmpfs:
    - /var/run/mysqld:uid=999,gid=999
    - /tmp
    volumes:
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
volumes:
  mysql:
```

Trouble is, the `tmpfs` isn't being created. If I run an instance of the container using `docker-compose run --rm mysql /bin/bash`, the `/var/run/mysqld` directory is still read-only despite the `tmpfs` entry, and any attempt to `touch /var/run/mysqld/foo` fails. Since this is where MySQL puts its socket and pid file, this causes the whole thing to fail. I'm not sure why the `tmpfs` entry isn't working in this case.

```
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:45 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:48 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:48 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:48 140515784030144 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 239403989
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:48 140515005662976 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:48 140515784030144 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:49 140515784030144 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:49 140515784030144 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Read-only file system
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:49 140515784030144 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
mysql_1    | 2017-01-27 20:53:49 140515784030144 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I can verify the permissions on the directory are correct (and that the UID of the `mysql` user is 999):

```
$ ls -la /var/run/mysqld 
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan 17 22:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Jan 18 22:55 ..
```

But I still cannot:

```
$ touch /var/run/mysqld/foo
touch: cannot touch '/var/run/mysqld/foo': Read-only file system
```

Even if I run as root.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

As an aside, the `/tmp` filesystem works fine.

Comment: Are you using docker swarm? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tmpfs says "Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file."

Comment: Nope. Straight up docker-compose.

Comment: Me too. (filler)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have been doing some testing in this regards, it looks like the `/var/run` directory is special in docker.

Here is some sample config and output:

```
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    command: "bash -c 'mount'"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/run
      - /var/cache
```

Running `docker-compose up ubuntu` shows what is mounted. Can see `/var/cache` is mounted but `/var/run` isn't.

```
...
ubuntu_1           | tmpfs on /var/cache type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
...
```

If you use `docker-compose run ubuntu bash` you can see it's also mounted there but not `/var/run`.

The reason is that `/var/run` is normally a symlink to `/run` and hence you creating `/var/run/mysql` as a tmpfs doesn't work.

It will work if you change it to `/run/mysql`, but `/run` is normally mounted as tmpfs anyway so you might as well just make `/run` a tmpfs. Like so:

```
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    command: "bash -c 'mount'"
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /var/cache
```

Note: I'd like to amend my answer and show the way to do it using `volumes`:

```
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    command: "bash -c 'mount'"
    volumes:
      - cache_vol:/var/cache
      - run_vol:/run

volumes:
  run_vol:
    driver_opts:
      type: tmpfs
      device: tmpfs
  cache_vol:
    driver_opts:
      type: tmpfs
      device: tmpfs
```

This also allows you to share the `tmpfs` mounts if needed.

Comment: According to documentation tmpfs  mounts cannot be shared among containers: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/tmpfs/#limitations-of-tmpfs-containers

Comment: Yes the `tmpfs` mount cannot, but above is a volume that is using the tmpfs type. Which is not a tmpfs mount but a volume mount using the tmpfs device. Which in theory can be shared like any other volume.

Comment: Has Docker's behaviour changed recently in this regard, as I used be able to tmpfs mount `/var/run/` and this has only stopped working today during a reboot on a frequently updated CoreOS machine.

Comment: Bardi it's probably because /var/run is a symlink

Comment: @dalore Tmpfs's lifespan is normally 1:1 with the container's lifespan.  If multiple containers share a volume using the tmpfs type and device, then what becomes of the lifecycle of the data in the volume?

Comment: Good question Jonathan, since it's a volume mount of the tmpfs type it would persist. Like other volumes do

Answer (score 11):

it some images like `alpine` the directory `/var/run` is just a link to `/run`
you can verify that using

```
$ docker run --rm -ti mariadb:10.1 ls -lh /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug  7 13:02 /var/run -> /run
```

which means that `/var/run/mysqld` is actually `/run/mysqld`

your updated docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    read_only: true
    tmpfs:
    - /run/mysqld:uid=999,gid=999
    - /tmp
    volumes:
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
volumes:
  mysql:
```

in that case just make your tmpfs point to `/run`

> it looks like the /var/run directory is special in docker.

no, it's just because it's a link

Comment: Thanks, `:uid=999,gid=999` fixed my issue with non-writable directory.